# I have sound on settings test but nowhere else (browser, VideoPlayer)

Tags: sound

Device: dell n5110, OS:Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I had sound before, but today (maybe after system update)
no sound at all on every browser and VLC, tried headphones, no hope.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have the correct default device selected?

Comment: I did, I am thinking this is maybe bug of ubuntu 18, because day before this issue I was using TV via HDMI and then I had option of two default devices at same time, and I choose only TV(external-monitor) sound

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, Ubuntu have bug, If you leave sound source as only TV and then turn it off. next time you turn on integrated speaker will be muted for apps.